# How to set text color in android.support.design.chip.Chip?

Tags: java, android, colors, android-chips

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="4dp"
     android:checked="true"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
     app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/selector"
     app:chipText="Test"
     app:chipIconEnabled="true"
     app:chipIconSize="20dp" />
```

In XML there is no attribute like:

```
chipTextColor
```

Programmatically SpannableString not working:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
String numeric = getString(R.string.patient_list_order_date);
SpannableString whiteSpannable= new SpannableString(numeric);
whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, numeric.length(), 0);
builder.append(whiteSpannable);
chip.setChipText(builder);
```

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: The solution adopted unfortunately is a workaround. With supportLibraryVersion 28.0.0-alpha3 the attribute `app:chipText` is not available anymore instead at classic `android:text`. Now the class `SpannableString` with specific `foregroundColorSpan` works

Comment: Good.Got the point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I managed to set the text-color in 28.0.0-alpha3 like this:

```
chip.setChipText(text);
chip.setTextAppearanceResource(R.style.ChipTextStyle_Selected);
```

and create a style with these parameters:

```
<style name="ChipTextStyle_Selected">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Worked for me after trying by myself from quite a while. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: After debugging one day issue got fixed, it worked in HTC device 5.1.1 thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use android:textColor in xml like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Or programatically you can use:

```
val chip = view.findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chip)
chip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In support library version 28  you can use this code for set color to text in chip

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

and this code for write text in chip

```
android:text="example"
```

Answer (score 0):

> public class Chip  extends AppCompatCheckBox implements
>   ChipDrawable.Delegate

[**`Chips`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip) are compact elements that represent an attribute, text, entity, or action. There is no **`app:chipTextColor`** attribute right now.

**FYI**

The Material Design color system can be used to create a color theme that reflects your brand or style.

Read the official guideline about [**`The color system`**](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#).

**NOTE**

You can try with [**`ForegroundColorSpan`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan)

**DEMO**

```
    SpannableString whiteSpannable= new SpannableString(numeric);
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_name);
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs  =new ForegroundColorSpan(color);
    whiteSpannable.setSpan(new 
    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),0,numeric.length(), 0);
    builder.append(whiteSpannable);
    chip.setChipText(builder);
```